# Help in Solving a linear Partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I can not to solve the following equation
$$(*) \qquad u''(r) +2n\coth(r)\,u'(r)+ (n^2+\lambda^2) \, u(r)= 0 \quad \mbox{with} \, r>0$$
where $n\in \mathbb N$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb C $.

That I have the transformed into the equation in $z$ follows
$$(* *) \qquad z^{ ''}(r) + \left(  \frac{n(1-n)}{\sinh^{2}(r)}+\lambda^{2}  \right) z(r) = 0, \quad \mbox{with} \, r>0$$
with $u(r)=g(r) z(r)$, where $g(r) = \dfrac{1}{\sinh^{n}(r)}$.

Someone can help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the substitution $s(r) = \cosh r$ and write $z(r) = Z(s(r))$. Then you obtain for $Z$ the differential equation
\begin{equation}
(1-s^2)Z''(s) - s Z'(s) + \left(\frac{n(n-1)}{1-s^2}+\lambda^2\right) Z(s) = 0,
\end{equation}
which is (a form of the) the [associated Legendre equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14). In this case, you can obtain the `proper' associated Legendre equation by introducing $\zeta(s) = (s^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{4}} Z(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sinh r}} \,Z(\cosh r)$. Eventually, you will obtain
\begin{equation}
z(r) = \sqrt{\sinh r} \left[c_1 P_{i \lambda - \frac{1}{2}}^{n-\frac{1}{2}}(\cosh r) + c_2 Q_{i \lambda - \frac{1}{2}}^{n-\frac{1}{2}}(\cosh r) \right],
\end{equation}
where $P_\nu^\mu(z)$ and $Q_\nu^\mu(z)$ are the standard solutions to the associated Legendre equation; see the DLMF link for relevant transformation rules which might simplify your expressions.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but just, I made the change of variable $\zeta(s) = (s^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{4}} Z(s)$, but I do not find the `proper' associated Legendre equation given by $$\left(  \left(1-x^{2}\right) \frac{d^2}{dx^2}-2x\frac{d}{dx} +\left(\nu(\nu+1)
-\frac{\mu^2}{1-x^2} \right)    \right)w=0$$

Comment: I rechecked: plugging $Z(s) = (s^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}} \zeta(s)$ into the equation for $Z$ yields the associated Legendre equation, multiplied by a prefactor $-(s^2-1)^\frac{1}{4}$, with $\nu(\nu+1) = -\lambda^2-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\mu^2 = \frac{1}{4}+n(n-1)$. Modulo some plus/minus mistakes, it's there.

Comment: we have \begin{align*} Z(s) &= (s^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}} \zeta(s);\\
\longrightarrow Z'(s) &= \frac{s}{2} (s^2-1)^{\frac{-3}{4}} \zeta(s)+(s^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}} \zeta'(s);\\
\longrightarrow Z''(s) &= (s^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}} \zeta''(s) +s (s^2-1)^{\frac{-3}{4}} \zeta'(s)+ \left( \frac{1}{2} (s^2-1)^{\frac{-3}{4}} -  \frac{3}{4} s^2 (s^2-1)^{\frac{-7}{4}} \right) \zeta(s) .
\end{align*}
we find
\begin{equation}
(1-s^2)\zeta''(s) - 2 s \zeta'(s) + \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{n(n-1)}{1-s^2}+\lambda^2 +-\frac{1}{4}\frac{s^2}{s^2-1} \right) \zeta(s) = 0,
\end{equation}
Is that's what bothers me!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You can write $\frac{s^2}{s^2-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{s^2-1}$, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Good evening Frits Veerman, I tried to simplify the expression of the solution using the DLMF link, but I can not, is that you can help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm afraid the associated Legendre functions are as close at you can get to an explicit expression for the solution. For integer values of $n$ though, you might find [this link][1] useful, when combined with [this expression][2]. Both are from the Wolfram Functions site, where you can generally find more detailed expressions than on DLMF. I hope this answers your question, since there isn't much else to simplify at this stage. 

[1]: http://functions.wolfram.com/07.08.17.0012.01
[2]: http://functions.wolfram.com/07.08.03.0093.01